# mpi_gather for struct with dynamic array

Tags: mpi

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct 
{ 
double distance;
int* path;
} tour;
```

Then I trying to gather results from all processes:

```
   MPI_Gather(&best, sizeof(tour), MPI_BEST, all_best, sizeof(tour)*proc_count, MPI_BEST, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

After gather my root see that all_best containts only 1 normal element and trash in others.
Type of  all_best is tour*.

Initialisation of MPI_BEST:

```
 void ACO_Build_best(tour *tour,int city_count, MPI_Datatype *mpi_type /*out*/)
 {
int block_lengths[2];
MPI_Aint displacements[2];
MPI_Datatype typelist[2];
MPI_Aint start_address;
MPI_Aint address;

block_lengths[0] = 1;
block_lengths[1] = city_count;

typelist[0] = MPI_DOUBLE;
typelist[1] = MPI_INT;

MPI_Address(&(tour->distance), &displacements[0]);
MPI_Address(&(tour->path), &displacements[1]);

displacements[1] = displacements[1] - displacements[0];
displacements[0] = 0;

MPI_Type_struct(2, block_lengths, displacements, typelist, mpi_type);
MPI_Type_commit(mpi_type);
}
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from passing incorrect lengths to `MPI_Gather`, MPI actually does not follow pointers to pointers. With such a structured type you would be sending the value of `distance` and the value of the `path` pointer (essentially an address which makes no sense when sent to other processes). If one supposes that `distance` essentially gives the number of elements in `path`, then you can kind of achieve your goal with a combination of `MPI_Gather` and `MPI_Gatherv`:

First, gather the lengths:

```c
int counts[proc_count];

MPI_Gather(&best->distance, 1, MPI_INT, counts, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Now that `counts` is populated with the correct lengths, you can continue and use `MPI_Gatherv` to receive all paths:

```c
int disps[proc_count];

disps[0] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < proc_count; i++)
   disps[i] = disps[i-1] + counts[i-1];
// Allocate space for the concatenation of all paths
int *all_paths = malloc((disps[proc_count-1] + counts[proc_count-1])*sizeof(int));
MPI_Gatherv(best->path, best->distance, MPI_INT,
            all_paths, counts, disps, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Now you have the concatenation of all paths in `all_paths`. You can examine or extract an individual path by taking `counts[i]` elements starting at position `disps[i]` in `all_paths`. Or you can even build an array of `tour` structures and make them use the already allocated and populated path storage:

```c
tour *all_best = malloc(proc_count*sizeof(tour));
for (int i = 0; i < proc_count; i++)
{
   all_best[i].distance = counts[i];
   all_best[i].path = &all_paths[disps[i]];
}
```

Or you can duplicate the segments instead:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < proc_count; i++)
{
   all_best[i].distance = counts[i];
   all_best[i].path = malloc(counts[i]*sizeof(int));
   memcpy(all_best[i].path, &all_paths[disps[i]], counts[i]*sizeof(int));
}
// all_paths is not needed any more and can be safely free()-ed
```

Edit: Because I've overlooked the definition of the `tour` structure, the above code actually works with:

```c
struct
{
   int distance;
   int *path;
}
```

where `distance` holds the number of significant elements in `path`. This is different from your case, but without some information on how `tour.path` is being allocated (and sized), it's hard to give a specific solution.

Comment: Are you sure that counts[0] and  all_paths[0] will be from the same element?

Comment: @T_T, `MPI_Gather[v]` orders the received chunks by the ranks of the processes, so `counts[0]` will always be the number of elements in rank `0` and `all_paths[0]` will be the first item in the path from rank `0`. But now I see that `distance` is not integer, so things become more complex. Could you show how `tour.path` is being allocated?

Comment: I've changed type of distance to int. Your answer helped. Thank you.